# java.time.DateTimeFormatter cannot parse without separator chars

Tags: java, parsing, java-8, datetime-format, formatter

```
java.time.LocalDateTime success = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("20 01 2014 15 36 21 234",java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd MM yyyy HH mm ss SSS"));             
java.time.LocalDateTime fails   = java.time.LocalDateTime.parse("20012014153621234",java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMMyyyyHHmmssSSS"));
```

reference: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Question:
The formatter/parser seems to not distinguisch between fixed and variable items.
eg. d="day-of-month" used as "dd" could be one or two digits (eg. 8 or 18).
Therefore the parser does not use "fixed" lengths as it tries to parse the next "item".
But the "items" are not separated and the parsing fails.

Am i right? Is there a fix for this?

Edit: Interestingly this works:

```
java.time.LocalDate date1   = java.time.LocalDate.parse("20140120", java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd"));
java.time.LocalTime time1   = java.time.LocalTime.parse("153621234", java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmmssSSS"));
```

but why not for Date+Time ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is java.time failing to parse fraction-of-second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588051/is-java-time-failing-to-parse-fraction-of-second)

Comment: What about my description @MisterSmith? I did not found suitable explanation in the reference provided by you!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman The explanation is that this is a bug. There's even a [JDK issue](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8031085) linked in the accepted answer.

Comment: @MisterSmith It certainly looks like a Java 8 bug since the code runs fine on Java 9.