# Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing LocalDateTime (Java 8)

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, datetime-format

I am simply trying to convert a date string into a DateTime object in Java 8. Upon running the following lines:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDateTime dt = LocalDateTime.parse("20140218", formatter);
```

I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: 
Text '20140218' could not be parsed: 
Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: 
{},ISO resolved to 2014-02-18 of type java.time.format.Parsed
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1918)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1853)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

The syntax is identical to what has been suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463062/how-to-parse-format-dates-with-localdatetime-java-8), yet I am served with an exception. I am using `JDK-8u25`.

Comment: why are you using LocalDateTime without a time?

Answer (score 262, accepted):

It turns out Java does not accept a bare Date value as DateTime. Using LocalDate instead of LocalDateTime solves the issue:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse("20140218", formatter);
```

Comment: For what it's worth: I had this same problem even when using `LocalDate` and not `LocalDateTime`. The issue was that I had created my `DateTimeFormatter` using `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);`, so I had to use date pattern `uuuuMMdd` instead of `yyyyMMdd` (i.e. "year" instead of "year-of-era")!

Comment: @ZeroOne's comment should be included as part of the selected answer.

Comment: @gourabix I've posted my comment as a separate answer, you may upvote that one. Eventually it will surpass the accepted one in the number of votes...

Comment: @iulian-david 's answer was more helpful here and actually solved the problem of parsing a datetime that may or may not have a time part.

Comment: "Java does not accept a bare Date value as DateTime"! What a rediculous feature!

Comment: For those who don't want to convert to localeDate see Julian David answer

Answer (score 110):

If you really need to transform a date to a LocalDateTime object, you could use the LocalDate.atStartOfDay(). This will give you a LocalDateTime object at the specified date, having the hour, minute and second fields set to 0:

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDateTime time = LocalDate.parse("20140218", formatter).atStartOfDay();
```

Comment: Correction: set to *whatever time it would be at the start of that day*.

Comment: `LocalDateTime.from` seems unnecessary, as `atStartOfDay()` already returns `LocalDateTime`.

Comment: scala: 
val time = LocalDate.parse("20171220", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd")).atStartOfDay.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"))

Answer (score 91):

For what is worth if anyone should read again this topic(like me) the correct answer would be in `DateTimeFormatter` definition, e.g.:

```
private static DateTimeFormatter DATE_FORMAT =  
            new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("dd/MM/yyyy[ [HH][:mm][:ss][.SSS]]")
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
            .toFormatter();
```

One should set the optional fields if they will appear. And the rest of code should be exactly the same.

Edit : usefull thing from wittyameta comment :

> Remember to add the parseDefaulting AFTER you have called appendPattern. Otherwise it'll give DateTimeParseException

Comment: This is true universal solution for instance for such method:
Long getFileTimestamp(String file, Pattern pattern, DateTimeFormatter dtf, int group);
Here you have different patterns and DateTimeFormetter, w/ and w/o time specified.

Comment: Can it be a static field? I have not found in the Javadoc that an instance created that way is thread-safe

Comment: Remember to add the `parseDefaulting` AFTER you have called `appendPattern`. Otherwise it'll give `DateTimeParseException`.

Comment: when using ```HH``` for hours in the pattern, i get 00 for AM hours

Comment: If you want to parse fraction of second by JAVA 8, try to visit this log.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588051/is-java-time-failing-to-parse-fraction-of-second

Answer (score 47):

For anyone who landed here with this error, like I did:

`Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {HourOfAmPm=0, MinuteOfHour=0}`

It came from a the following line:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy h:mm"));
```

It turned out that it was because I was using a 12hr Hour pattern on a 0 hour, instead of a 24hr pattern.

Changing the hour to 24hr pattern by using a capital H fixes it:

```
LocalDateTime.parse(date, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d/yy H:mm"));
```

Answer (score 41):

This is a really unclear and unhelpful error message. After much trial and error I found that `LocalDateTime` will give the above error if you do not attempt to parse a time. By using `LocalDate` instead, it works without erroring.

This is poorly documented and the related exception is very unhelpful.

Answer (score 37):

Expanding on [retrography's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27454146/1333157)..: I had this same problem even when using `LocalDate` and not `LocalDateTime`. The issue was that I had created my `DateTimeFormatter` using `.withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);`, so I had to use date pattern `uuuuMMdd` instead of `yyyyMMdd` (i.e. "year" instead of "year-of-era")!

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
  .parseStrict()
  .appendPattern("uuuuMMdd")
  .toFormatter()
  .withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
LocalDate dt = LocalDate.parse("20140218", formatter);
```

(This solution was originally a comment to retrography's answer, but I was encouraged to post it as a stand-alone answer because it apparently works really well for many people.)

Comment: The answer to why "u" instead of "y"has been answered in this link [uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177442/uuuu-versus-yyyy-in-datetimeformatter-formatting-pattern-codes-in-java) @Peru

Answer (score 19):

If the date String does not include any value for hours, minutes and etc you cannot directly convert this to a `LocalDateTime`. You can only convert it to a `LocalDate`, because the string **only** **represent** the **year,month and date** components it would be the correct thing to do.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("20180306", dtf); // 2018-03-06
```

Anyway you can convert this to `LocalDateTime`.

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyyMMdd");
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse("20180306", dtf);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.of(ld, LocalTime.of(0,0)); // 2018-03-06T00:00
```

Comment: Also make sure the format is correct. This fix didn't work for me until because I set the format to `yyyy-mm-dd` when it should have been `yyyy-MM-dd`.

Comment: I want to upvote this 10 times if I can

Answer (score 6):

```
 DateTimeFormatter format = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                            .appendPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")
                            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0)
                            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MINUTE_OF_HOUR, 0)
                            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE, 0)
                            .parseDefaulting(ChronoField.MILLI_OF_SECOND, 0)
                            .toFormatter();
```

Works for me

Comment: for minimum, only `ChronoField.HOUR_OF_DAY` is needed, it does the same thing with the other 3 removed (`MINUTE_OF_HOUR`, `SECOND_OF_MINUTE`, `MILLI_OF_SECOND`)

Answer (score 4):

## You do not need to define a `DateTimeFormatter`

You do not need to define a `DateTimeFormatter` to parse the given date string. You can use the OOTB (Out-Of-The-Box), `DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE` to parse it.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse("20140218", DateTimeFormatter.BASIC_ISO_DATE);
        System.out.println(date);

        // In case you need an instance of LocalDateTime
        LocalDateTime ldt = date.atTime(LocalTime.MIN);
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2014-02-18
2014-02-18T00:00
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/MNxwV7)

Learn more about the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table). Note that Android 8.0 Oreo already provides [support for `java.time`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/package-summary). Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67752047/10819573) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67505173/10819573) to learn how to use `java.time` API with JDBC.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In cases where you simply want to take a format (whether or not it has time) and want to parse to a LocalDateTime, you can do the following.

```java
LocalDateTime parseDateTime(String dateTime, DateTimeFormatter fmt) {
  return fmt.parse(dateTime, t -> {
    LocalDate date = t.query(TemporalQueries.localDate());
    LocalTime time = t.query(TemporalQueries.localTime());
    return LocalDateTime.of(date, time != null ? time : LocalTime.MIDNIGHT);
  });
}
```

I needed this because I was getting the date/time pattern as a parameter for a custom Spark UDF.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine

```
public class DateDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm");
        String date = "16-08-2018 12:10";
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.parse(date, formatter);
        System.out.println("VALUE="+localDate);

        DateTimeFormatter formatter1 = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm");
        LocalDateTime parse = LocalDateTime.parse(date, formatter1);
        System.out.println("VALUE1="+parse);
    }
}
```

output:

```
VALUE=2018-08-16
VALUE1=2018-08-16T12:10
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
LocalDate fromLocalDate = LocalDate.parse(fromdstrong textate, dateTimeFormatter);
```

You can add any format you want. That works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this problem because my input string didn't have a year in it:

input string:  `Tuesday, June 8 at 10:00 PM`
formatter:  `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d 'at' h:mm a", Locale.US);`

I knew the year so I just appended it to get:

input string:  `Tuesday, June 8 at 6:30 PM 2021`
formatter:  `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE, MMMM d 'at' h:mm a uuuu", Locale.US);`