# Turn String into LocalDateTime Object

Tags: java, data-structures

Why won't this work? I don't understand the error it is giving me.

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.time.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        String str = "2004 Jul";
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy MMM");
        LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);

        System.out.println(dateTime);
    }
}
```

I get this error:
[image: error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `LocalDate` instead, apparently `LocalDateTime` tries to parse for a [time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime) as well.