# Parse clock time in java 8

Tags: parsing, datetime, java-8, java-time

I wonder is it possible to parse clock time hour:minute:second in Java 8?

e.g.

```
final DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HH:mm:ss");
final String str = "12:22:10";
final LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(str, formatter);
```

I tried but get this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '12:22:10' could not be parsed: Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor: {},ISO resolved to 12:22:10 of type java.time.format.Parsed
```

Comment: Duplicate of _[Unable to obtain LocalDateTime from TemporalAccessor when parsing LocalDateTime (Java 8)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27454025/unable-to-obtain-localdatetime-from-temporalaccessor-when-parsing-localdatetime)_.

Comment: @Diti Don't think it's the same issue. The link you have provided is parsing a bare date without time. Where as my issue is parsing bare time without date.

Comment: Fundamentally, it's the same issue: you're trying to parse into a `LocalDateTime` but you have no date, so which date is supposed to be parsed? Parse into a `LocalTime` instead, that will work.

Comment: @Tunaki@Diti Thanks for clarifying, that works!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

## `LocalTime.parse`

Since you only have a time use the [`LocalTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalTime.html) class. No need to define a formatting pattern in your case.

```
String str = "12:22:10";
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse(str);
```

See that code [run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/vSDsrJ).

See [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) for more info.

Comment: Since it's a standard format, you can simply use `LocalTime.parse(str);`.

Comment: FYI, see a chart I made comparing the various date-time types including `LocalTime`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WyAl2.png

Answer (score 2):

LocalTime.parse("04:17");