# Parse week-based-year and week-of-week-based-year without separator character fails

Tags: java, localdate

I'm trying to parse a week-based-year and week-of-week-based-year from a string without any separator character. E.g. "201812" (week 12 of year 2018). Like this:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("YYYYww")
                                    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
                                    .toFormatter();
LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("201803", formatter);
```

But this gives me:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '201803' could not be parsed at index 0
```

If I add a space between the fields like so:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
                                    .appendPattern("YYYY ww")
                                    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
                                    .toFormatter();
LocalDate parse = LocalDate.parse("2018 03", formatter);
```

It works fine, with result:

```
2018-01-15
```

[Is this another bug like this one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22588051/is-java-time-failing-to-parse-fraction-of-second) Or am I missing something?

The workaround I found was building a custom formatter:

```
DateTimeFormatter yearWeekPattern = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 4)
    .appendValue(IsoFields.WEEK_OF_WEEK_BASED_YEAR, 2)
    .parseDefaulting(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), 1)
    .toFormatter();
LocalDate.parse("201803", yearWeekPattern).atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a **known bug** which has been [fixed for Java-9](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8145633).

---

If you are still on Java-8 and cannot move to Java-9 then

- you are either out of luck
- or you can use a 3rd-party-library.

**[Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/):** (uses "x" for week-based-year)

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter =
    new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern("xxxxww").toFormatter();
LocalDate joda = LocalDate.parse("201803", formatter);
System.out.println(joda); // 2018-01-15
```

A replacement for `parseDefaulting()` is not available.

**Time4J** ([my lib](https://github.com/MenoData/Time4J)):

```
ChronoFormatter<CalendarWeek> f =
    ChronoFormatter.ofPattern(
        "YYYYww",
        PatternType.CLDR,
        Locale.ROOT,
        CalendarWeek.chronology()
    );
CalendarWeek cw = f.parse("201803");
java.time.LocalDate d = cw.at(Weekday.MONDAY).toTemporalAccessor();
System.out.println(d); // 2018-01-15
```

The replacement for `parseDefaulting()` can be achieved if you set up the formatter not for the type `CalendarWeek` but the basic type `PlainDate` and use this general formatter method [withDefault(...)](http://time4j.net/javadoc-en/net/time4j/format/expert/ChronoFormatter.html#withDefault-net.time4j.engine.ChronoElement-V-). Example:

```
ChronoFormatter<PlainDate> f =
    ChronoFormatter
        .ofDatePattern("YYYYww", PatternType.CLDR, Locale.ROOT)
        .withDefault(PlainDate.DAY_OF_WEEK, Weekday.MONDAY);
PlainDate cw = f.parse("201803");
java.time.LocalDate d = cw.toTemporalAccessor();
```

Comment: Of couse, the simplest workaround would just be parsing the extended ISO-notation: `input.substring(0, 4) + "-" + input.substring(4)` but I have left it out of my answer because I assume that you look for a library-based solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Good to know it's a bug. I actually did find a workaround (I edited my question to add it).

Comment: @fassen Fine, the builder approach is also good because it instructs the parser to only parse 4 digits for the week-based-year, not more.