# java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06/05/2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Tags: java

I am having this error time when I tried to format a date.
here is the code snippet.

```
private LocalDate expirationDate;

public static String convertIntlToStandard(String dateTpChange) {
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(dateTpChange)) {
        DateTimeFormatter oldformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        LocalDate formatDateTime = LocalDate.parse(dateTpChange, oldformatter);
        DateTimeFormatter newformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        return formatDateTime.format(newformatter);
    } else {
        return dateTpChange;
    }
}

boPrescriptionResponse.setExpirationDate(LocalDate.parse(DateUtils.convertIntlToStandard(boPrescription.getExpirationDate().toString())));
```

> java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '06/05/2019' could not be parsed at index 0

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949513/unable-to-parse-string-into-java-8-localdatetime/60949757?noredirect=1#comment107831974_60949757

Comment: that is to be expected. As you try to parse a string with the pattern `MM/dd/yyyy` with a formatter for `yyyy-MM-dd` the formatter will not be able to convert the pattern and throw an exception.
So you'd need to check the pattern first.

Specifically: the year `06/0` is unparseable.

Comment: Why do you expect the `dateTpChange` string value of `"06/05/2019"` would parse without error when using a formatter with pattern `"yyyy-MM-dd"`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to parse string into Java 8 LocalDateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60949513/unable-to-parse-string-into-java-8-localdatetime)

Comment: The naming of your method is ambiguous, as `yyyy-MM-dd` is the standard (ISO-8601).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you switched `oldformatter` and `newformatter`:

```java
public static String convertIntlToStandard(String dateTpChange) {
    if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(dateTpChange)) {
        DateTimeFormatter oldformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
        LocalDate formatDateTime = LocalDate.parse(dateTpChange, oldformatter);
        DateTimeFormatter newformatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd");
        return formatDateTime.format(newformatter);
    } else {
        return dateTpChange;
    }
}
```